# How to fix "Captured variable is disposed in the outer scope"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I create a scope in each loop iteration. I use it in ProcessMessageAsync. However, I get "Captured variable is disposed of in the outer scope," even though the scope will not be destroyed until the await finishes.

```
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested 
                   && !taskToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
                var errorReporter = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ErrorReporter>();
                
                await errorReporter.DefineScope(() => ProcessMessageAsync(scope, cancellationToken));
            }
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Until what be finished... DefineScope and you are passing it to ProcessMessageAsync

Comment: You are passing a _callback_ to `DefineScope()`. You are using `scope` inside that callback (that's what the 'captured variable' refers to). You don't know when the callback will actually be called

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, so basically, if I am sure that it will not be used after awaiting, I can just ignore the warning?

Comment: You _could_ ignore it, but if ErrorReporter is scoped then I would suggest changing the DefineScope method. It could leverage the existing DI scope instead of making its own

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "*Captured variable is disposed of in the outer scope,*" is likely due to the fact that you are using the scope variable within an asynchronous operation (ProcessMessageAsync). **When the using block completes, the scope variable is disposed of, but the asynchronous operation may still be executing.** As a result, when the operation completes and attempts to access the disposed scope variable, the error occurs.

**To resolve this issue, you can capture the scope variable in a separate variable that will remain in scope for the duration of the asynchronous operation. Here's an updated version of your code snippet:**

```
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested 
       && !taskToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var errorReporter = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ErrorReporter>();
    var currentScope = scope; // Capture scope in a separate variable
                
    await errorReporter.DefineScope(() => ProcessMessageAsync(currentScope, cancellationToken));
}
```